# International Email validation in C++ using Regex

Tags: c++, regex

I am facing some issues in validating international email addresses like `john.doe@神谕.com`, `sara.smith@神谕.com`, `babu.ratnakar+आଆఉఊګ神谕@gmail.com`,
`testæœö.神谕#$&*éùôß@äßæçëêùé+आଆ神谕.com` using REGEX in C++

The following Regex worked fine for me in Java:

```
^[\\p{L}0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[\\p{L}0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9])?\\.)+[\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9])?$
```

I tried using the same with slight modification in C++

```
std::string str("[\\\\p{L}0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\\\\p{L}0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[\\\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\\\p{L}0-9])?\.)+[\\\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\\\p{L}0-9])?"); 

std::regex rx4(str);
```

But `regex_match` fails on all cases. I think the issue is with `\p{L}`. When I replaced that with `a-z`, it accepts email addresses with english alphabets. ie this one is working:

```
std::regex rx3("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", std::regex::ECMAScript);
```

`/p{L}` to match unicode letters won't work in C++ ?

Comment: Did you obey the correct escaping (`\\`) when you build the regex string?

Comment: Short answer: [don't](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/). Or at least, don't try too hard. You'll need to send them a verification email anyway, so just use a simple regex and then try to email them.

Comment: yeah, I believe the escaping was correct. The only additional thing I had to put in was two more forward slashes '\' before '\\p{L}'

Comment: As pointed out - escaping. Java and c++ escape the same way so \\ should stay as it is, **not** \\\\.

Comment: When I kept it as just two slashes ie \\p{L} am getting the following error Microsoft C++ exception: std::tr1::regex_error at memory location 0x047fcbfc

Comment: I wonder if `"^(?:(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]{2,})$"` works for you. It is posted [on SO here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3832970).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ `std::regex` [supports 6 regex flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html):

> **Six different regular expression flavors or grammars are defined in `std::regex_constants`**:
>
> `ECMAScript`: Similar to JavaScript
> `basic`: Similar to POSIX BRE.
> `extended`: Similar to POSIX ERE.
> `grep`: Same as basic, with the addition of treating line feeds as alternation operators.
> `egrep`: Same as extended, with the addition of treating line feeds as alternation operators.
> `awk`: Same as extended, with the addition of supporting common escapes for non-printable characters.

None of these support *Unicode properties* (or *Unicode category classes*) like `\p{L}`, thus you cannot use `\p{L}` in your patterns.

Use your workaround if it works for you:

```
std::regex rx3("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", std::regex::ECMAScript);
```

Or a version from a [known *Validate email address in JavaScript?* SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3832970) (removing anchors since you are using `regex_match` and re-escaping for use with a non-raw string literal, and `std::regex::ECMAScript` since it is used by default):

```
std::regex rx3("(?:(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^<>()‌​\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]{2,})")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But still finding some issues. I have used the regex in both java and C++. But the mail id 伊昭傑@郵件.商務 is accepted in java but rejected in C++         .   The regex  "^(?:(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^<>()‌​\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]{2,})$" is used in Java.                                                                             In C++, std::regex rx3("(?:(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^<>()‌​\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]{2,})") is used.

Comment: Use [`^\S+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/jB9eG8/1), why restrict the email so much?

Comment: Yeah. I understand. But trying to understand the diff here. Behaviour should be the same in java and cpp, right?

Comment: Is there any equivalent of \p{L} in C++ ?

Comment: Use Boost regex library, or PCRE, PCRE2, they have Unicode category support. BTW, `std::regex reg(R"((?:(?:[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+(?:\.[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]{2,}))");` matches your email. See https://ideone.com/d26xH2

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry for keep on asking silly doubts. Am a novice in this. Am getting compilation issue - R : undeclared identifier.

Comment: This is a raw string literal that you might not have support of since you are using TR1. You should really be using `std::regex`, not TR1 regex. Unless you are using Visual Studio 2008. `R"((?:(?:[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+(?:\.[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^‌​<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]{2,}))"` = `"(?:(?:[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(?:\\.[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|\".+\")@(?:(?:[^‌​<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+\\.)+[^<>()\\[\\].,;:\\s@\"]{2,})"`.